# Empty grid space in component

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have a grid inside a component which has some rows and columns. The problem is that there is some empty space after the last row of the grid and I want to get rid of it. [image] This is what it looks like in the inspector, it actually shows that the whole content is the grid, whereas only the rows with actual information are the content of the grid. I want to remove this white space which is there for no reason. For clarification this is the empty unwanted space: [image]

Comment: How did you set the height of the Grid?

Comment: I used the method `setSizeFull()` on the grid.

Comment: So that's why you have this behavior. It uses the full height.

Comment: But should it use the full height? There is a Text Box at the bottom of the component, should it be spread over the entire component even then? When the component is made smaller, the grid always seems to contain the white space even though there is not much free space in the component itself, thus forcing the user to scroll.

Comment: Sometimes the horizontal scrollbar is not visible as it is pushed out of the visible component space.

Comment: size full ist height 100% and width 100% so if you have components below or above it will take to much space. Otherwise you have to calculate the space it should take.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235543/discussion-between-michael-krocka-and-simon-martinelli).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setHeightByRows` to set the Grid to contain a fixed amount of rows, or `setHeightUndefined` to always show all the rows (bad idea if your Grid ever has massive amounts of data in it).